# Squared error consistent is asymptotically unbiased lim$_{n→ \infty} E[(\hat\theta_n - \theta)^2] = 0$

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

An estimator $\hat\theta_n$ is said to be squared error consistent for $\theta$ if lim$_{n→ \infty} E[(\hat\theta_n - \theta)^2] = 0$

a) Show that any squared error consistent $\theta_n$ is asymptotically unbiased.

attempt: Let $E[(\hat\theta_n - \theta)^2] = E[\hat\theta^2_n - 2\theta\hat\theta_n + \theta^2] = E(\hat\theta^2_n) - 2\theta E(\hat\theta) + \theta^2 = E(\hat\theta^2_n) - [E(\theta_n)]^2 + [E(\theta_n)]^2 - 2\theta E(\hat\theta) + \theta^2 = Var(\hat\theta) + E[(\hat\theta) - \theta)]^2 $

Can someone please help me? I don't really know if this is a way to do it. Any help would be really appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} MSE(\hat{\theta}_n)=\lim \left( Var(\hat{\theta}_n)+b^2_n(\theta)\right)=0$, then $\lim b^2_n=0$, and $g(x)=x^2$ is continuous function for every $x$, thus $0=\lim b^2_n=(\lim b_n )^2$, taking square-root of both sides you get,
$$
\lim b_n = 0.
$$